# npm WARN when creating files from create-react-app

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

```
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 7.486s

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 1649 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
pc react_crash_todo % npm audit fix
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

up to date in 7.766s

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 1649 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated
pc react_crash_todo %
```

Im trying to start learning react and i got this error while creating the files using create-react-app application. also i have noticed that the error is happening due to tsutils and typescript is not installed i tried installing the same using below commands

sudo npm install -g tsutils
sudo npm install -g typescript

it showed that it got installed too

```
+ tsutils@3.17.1
added 2 packages from 2 contributors in 0.225s

+ typescript@3.9.7
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 3.226s
```

but im still getting the WARNING any idea how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can safely ignore these warnings. This is just a normal part of js development

Answer (score 0):

that's a `node_modules` package warning, You can safely ignore that warning.

```
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0
```

Means that `tsutils@3.17.1` doesn't use `typescript@>=2.8.0`. It's okay if the package of `tsutils` still run right without any problem. To resolve this you should bumb update the `tsutils` on your `node_modules` not your global project. It's okay the maintainer will do at some point and make that warning goes away. It is appropriate.